# Add external users in AAD Group to access Power BI workspace

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi

I want to allow external B2B users access Power BI workspace and it's contents. Essentially I need AAD group admins to manage their group users but not see or invite users from other groups and than these groups will have access to Power BI workspace.
Is this functionality possible out of the box or do i need to create custom solution?

Comment: There is no such a functionality out of the box currently.

Comment: @AllenWu do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: For b2b external access you need to add guest users https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-azure-ad-b2b

Comment: @Jon i don't want a single person to add users, what i want is to create AAD groups for different clients and admin from every group will be able to add additional users.

Comment: @unaseer. Are you still looking any on this question